# Как в 1С:Битрикс сделать многоуровневое меню?

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

1С Битрикс. Есть меню каталога товаров, в котором много уровней вложенности (например 10). Как вывести вложенность каталогов более чем 4?

[image: как это выглядит в админке]
[image: как это выглядит на сайте]
[image: максимально можно поставить значение 4]
1)Пробовал в 'bitrix/components/bitrix/menu/.parameters.php' добавлять свои параметры, затем в настройках выбирать их, но ничего не меняется.

[image: .parameters.php]
[image: components.php]
2) Пробовал в 'bitrix/components/bitrix/menu/component.php'
менять строку:
    if (isset($arParams["MAX_LEVEL"]) && 1 < intval($arParams["MAX_LEVEL"]) && intval($arParams["MAX_LEVEL"]) **< 5**)
на 
    if (isset($arParams["MAX_LEVEL"]) && 1 < intval($arParams["MAX_LEVEL"]) && intval($arParams["MAX_LEVEL"]) **< 10**)
, но не помогло.
[image: 6]
[image: 7]

3) Добавил в 'bitrix/components/bitrix/menu/templates/tree/template.php' чтобы посмотреть результат "$arResult", и увидел в массиве есть только "СуперФутболки1" и "СуперФутболки2", а '3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10' нет. Значит изначально запрос выбирает до иерархии 4. Значит нужно изменить чтобы "$arResult" выводил больше уровней каталога.
Где можно это изменить? Может кто сталкивался? Уже перекопал весь интернет и   ютуб, ничего толкового именно по этой теме нет.

[image: 8]

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал пересмотреть уровни вложенности. 10 уровней вряд-ли кто-то захочет проходить чтобы добраться до товаров. Но вопрос конечно интересен, хоть функционально он и не удобен с пользовательской точки зрения.

Comment: Чем обусловлена такая вложенность? Возможно использовать другой подход? Отображения/фильтрация по тегам? Торговые предложения?